# tying multiple functions together in a similar pattern excel

Tags: css, excel, function, ms-office

I am making a budget and whatnot in excel. I want to highlight a bunch of side by side rows, and say "for each of these rows on the left, make the row on the right equal to 12 * the left row", the left is the month cost, the right is the year.

I want the left side to change if I change the right, and the right to change if I change the left. I also want me other functions (the sums of these rows vertically) to not get damaged.

Is this possible en masse, where I can highlight 20 or more rows vertically and tell it the pattern? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Not without vba.  You would use the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: darn, still haven't learned vba. I can ask my roommate

Comment: Can you detail on what you mean by "change the left/right"? If you change the APT savings, how do you expect the Month & Year cells to change? If you can explain a little more on what you want, we can guide you, and hopefully even teach you some VBA along the way!

Comment: Mr. Batman, if you cut month in half for the water bill, the yearly water bill should cut in half

if you cut the yearly water bill in half, the monthly should drop by half. the yearly should always be 12 times the monthly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you stated you don't know VBA, and since it's fairly simple if you do know it, I thought I would help you out.

Place this inside the Worksheet Module in the VBE for the sheet where the budge information is. [Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html) is a tutorial on how to place the code in the worksheet module.

The only thing you may need to adjust is the range references (F3:F23 and G3:G23) to your actual cell references.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'if monthly data changes
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F3:F23")) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Target * 12
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

'if yearly data changes
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G3:G23")) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(, -1).Value = Target / 12
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How come the colors look funky in the code?  Nice thinking though with the Intersect.

Comment: @BruceWayne - no idea why the colors are funky ... copied the code straight from VBE. Usually doesn't do that.

Comment: I don't know any volunteer babywearing educators in my local area. Can you refer me?

http://babywearinginternational.org/2015/03/23/what-the-heck-is-a-vbe/

Comment: @codyc4321 - VBE is the Visual Basic Editor. Please see the link I referenced to show you how to incorporate the code. It's overall, pretty simple :)